# Rails multiple joins separated by or

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a query that will select all users that have an assignment (group or just assignment) that matches a condition. It is an easy thing to do in SQL but the result will be an array. I need the result to be ActiveRecord::Relation so I can apply more scopes to the result.

Normally it would like this - `"SELECT * from users JOINS assignments on (assignments.user_id = users.id) WHERE assignments.id > 5 OR JOINS group_assignments on (group_assignments.user_id = users.id) WHERE group_assignments.id > 5)"`

But I don't really know, how to do it using "joins" or "includes" - the scope under "both_assignments" does not really work and I don't know why.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :group_assignments

  scope :both_assignments, lambda {
   joins(:assignments).where(condition..)
     .or(joins(:group_assignments).where(condition...)
    }
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class GroupAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: I think that the OR operator in SQL isn't the most efficient way of going about it. Would it be possible for you to have two separate queries for this? One for assignments and one for group_assignments?